# Angular 4 Directive for Media Query Print

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

Trying to make a directive that will hide elements using a print media query. In plain CSS, it looks like this:

```
@media print {
  .no-print {
  display: none;
}
```

How can I apply this in a directive using elementRef, here's what I have so far:

```
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.setAttribute('style',
    `@media print {
    display: none;
    }`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like this :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {

  @HostBinding('class')
  elementClass = 'custom-theme';

  constructor() {
  }
}
```